# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax [elif my_move == 'rock']

Tags: python

I'm  developing a rock paper scissors on python and I'm getting this syntax error
any help is appreciated

```
class Player:
def move(self):
    return 'rock'

def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
    self.my_move = my_move
    self.their_move = their_movee here

class Game:
def __init__(self, p1, p2):
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2

def play_round(self):
    move1 = input("Pick something!\n")
    move2 = self.p2.move()
    print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
    self.p1.learn(move1, move2)
    self.p2.learn(move2, move1)
    my_score = 0 
    computer_score = 0
    if beats(move1, move2):
        my_score = my_score + 1
        print ("You win")
        print ("Human score = " + str(my_score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(computer_score) ) 
    elif beats(move2,move1):
        computer_score = computer_score + 1
        print ("Computer wins")
        print ("Human score = " + str(my_score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(computer_score) ) 
    else:
        print ("Draw")
        print ("Human score = " + str(my_score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(computer_score) )    

def play_game(self):
    print("Game start!")
    for round in range(3):
        print(f"Round {round}:")
        self.play_round()
    print("Game over!")

class cycleplayer(Player):
def move(self):
    if round == 0 :
        return 'rock'

    elif  self.my_move == 'rock'
        return "paper"   

    elif self.my_move == 'paper'
        return "scissors"  

    else self.my_move == 'scissors'
        return "rock"
```

on the cycleplayer subclass I want the program to take the previous move and use it in the current round

I get an error on the first elif in the subclass cycleplayer
the error points on "rock"

> invalid syntax ()

Comment: Please add the full error trackback!

Comment: Your missing `:` in your elif

Comment: and also `else` don't have an condition!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to the missing colons after your elif's and the disallowed condition following else, this might have an issue because of the white space. Be sure to indent the member functions within your classes!

Comment: It looks like the Player and cycleplayer classes doesn't have an __init__ function that guarantees the my_move attribute is set, so it's possible to instantiate one of these classes and call move(), then get this error. 

Edit: a big piece of advice I would give is to use an integrated development environment (IDE). This will make finding these situations much easier! I'd highly recommend PyCharm - if you're student, it's free